# How to make the background image to fit into the whole page without repeating using plain css?

Tags: css, background-image

I have an JPG image with size 1024 x 724. My page size is not fixed.
My requirement is:
If I resize the page then the background image should also resize and fit to the page.

Also I don't want to keep the image related information in my Html page/JSP. I want to do this using plain CSS. I am not using CSS3. Because there is an attribute called `background-size` which can make the image stretch to the page width and height. Currently only Google Chrome supports this. 
Any help ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can't resize background images with CSS2.

What you can do is have a container that resizes:

```
<div style='position:absolute;z-index:0;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%'>
  <img src='whatever.jpg' style='width:100%;height:100%' alt='[]' />
</div>
```

This way, the `div` will sit behind the page and take up the whole space, while resizing as needed.  The `img` inside will automatically resize to fit the `div`.

Comment: I don't want to keep the image and its source in Html page.

Comment: Simple solution! By the way, you can also use `left:0;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;` instead of `width:100%;height:100%`.

Comment: (Of course don't put the `style` attribute inline like my example; use a header style block or external sheet.)

Comment: @Multiplexer - if it's in CSS, it's already in the HTML page, in the background!

Comment: @Steve - But I have many different pages. If I keep at one place it won't apply to all the other pages. I want to keep this in all the other pages.

Comment: @Multiplexer - have a server-side script template that outputs the HTML code when you need it (I'd use PHP).  Not as hard as it sounds.

Comment: @Steve - I am using JSP. Is it possible to include that image in all the pages ?

Comment: @Multiplexer - yes, just make a function to output a string that's common to all pages, then call the function on each page, instead of writing a pile of code.

Comment: @Steve - I don't want to make change in all the pages. There are more than 100 pages are there.

Comment: @plex Well, then CSS3 (not widely supported) or Javascript (dynamically create and insert the absolute div on page load) sound like the only solutions remaining.  Or a CSS redesign/streamline.

Comment: Or a better server-side engine that allows you to easily change code in all pages at once. Really, this should not be a difficult problem. And, if it is, then you need to refactor some code, or even use a different tool for this job.

Comment: @Denilson Sá (re: left/top/right/bottom), this will break in IE 6, which will ignore the bottom and right values entirely. There's no reason in this case not to use width/height 100% aanyway.

Comment: width/height 100% might be not be a good idea if you have borders and padding. In this case, however, both solutions work. (and IE6 is broken in so many ways...)

Comment: Downvoted because this is incorrect:  "You can't resize background images with plain CSS."

Answer (score 16):

try something like

```
background: url(bgimage.jpg) no-repeat;
background-size: 100%;
```

Comment: Bear in mind that `background-size`, as a CSS3 property, is currently not very widely-supported and vendor extensions should be used as well for now.

Comment: Nowadays it's pretty secure to use this property! http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Comment: background:url(bgimage.jpg) no-repeat;
background-size: cover;

This did the trick

Answer (score 4):

You can either use JavaScript or CSS3.

**JavaScript solution:** Use an absolute positioned `<img>` tag and resize it on the page load and whenever the page resizes. Be careful of possible bugs when trying to get the page/window size.

**CSS3 solution:** Use the CSS3 [background-size](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-size) property. You might use either `100% 100%` or `contain` or `cover`, depending on how you want the image to resize. Of course, this only works on modern browsers.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what kind of image you have, it might be better to rework the design so that the main image fades to a set solid color or repeatable pattern. If you center the image in the page and have the solid color as the backgroud.

See http://www.webdesignerwall.com/trends/80-large-background-websites/ for examples of sites using large or scalable backgrounds.

Answer (score 1):

These three line all together worked for me.

```
background-image: url("pages/images/backImage.png");
background-size: 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 0):

background:url(bgimage.jpg) no-repeat;
background-size: cover;

This did the trick